# How i can programmatically get all the SharePoint team-sites?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development

In my SharePoint site in "SharePoint admin center" page (Admin-> SharePoint) I have a list of the teamsites of my organization. How can I get this list programmatically?

[image]

Comment: Is it sharepoint 2013 online or on -premise?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant.GetSiteProperties() method

Returns an enumerable collection of SiteProperties. The SiteProperties object has what you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.online.sharepoint.tenantadministration.tenant.getsiteproperties%28v=office.15%29.aspx

---

Also, the Office App Model Samples has a solution that uses search. http://officeams.codeplex.com/

Comment: But can i do that without admin permissions?

Comment: Anonymous access to capabilities to add and remove sites? No you cannot and you really do not want that...

Comment: Just read only. But i managed this by storing urls in database and getting them from it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a list of site collections,  you could use [SharePoint Online Administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132908%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to manage SharePoint Online (SPO).

PowerShell example:

```
#Connect to SPO
Connect-SPOService -Url https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com -credential usernam@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
#Retrieve all site collections
Get-SPOSite
```